# django rest framework display model instances

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I am trying to display all model instances.

Main Project `urls.py`:

```
from .views import api_root, endpoint_info, test

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test', test)
]
```

Main Project `views.py`:

```
from project.models import Project
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

@api_view(['GET'])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def test(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    for project in projects:
        return Response({'client_name': project.client_name})
        # return Response({'client_name': 'string_value_random'}) <-- tried returning string too
```

I get this error:

```
AssertionError at /test
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

Also I tried returing `return Response({'client_name': 'string_value_random'})` but still get the same error.

How should I display the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Project.objects.all()` results in an empty QuerySet, so your loop will not get run, which makes the function to implicitly return `None`.

Also, you need to ditch the loop and make your return statement be:

```
return Response({'projects': projects})
```